# After Effects animation loaded with Lottie not playing

Tags: ios, animation, after-effects, lottie

I'm using the [Lottie library for iOS](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios) and trying to load an animation in .json format downloaded [LottieFiles](https://www.lottiefiles.com/).

I'm using this code in the `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "infinite_rainbow")
animationView.loopAnimation = true
animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400)
animationView.center = self.view.center
animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
view.addSubview(animationView)
animationView.play()
```

**Problem:** just the first frame gets displayed, but the animation doesn't play. I have tried several files but the result is the same.

I'm using:

- Xcode 9.1
- Swift 4
- Lottie-ios v2.1.5 (cocoapod)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling .play() in viewDidAppear

Answer (score 1):

use content mode .scaleAspectFit instead of .scaleAspectFill

```
    let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "infinite_rainbow")
    animationView.loopAnimation = true
    animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400)
    animationView.center = self.view.center
    animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    view.addSubview(animationView)
    animationView.play()
```